# Select Something + An arbitrary Number in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, numbers

I have a situation where I need to do something like

```
select 2, id from users;
```

I think that would work at least with Oracle but it doesn't work in Mysql. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a problem with that query? What exactly is the problem? Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish, rather than how you think it should be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to assign a name for your arbitrary value:

```
SELECT 2 AS arbitrary_value, id FROM users;
```

Answer (score 0):

your request is ok. Maybe you sould define more precisely "Doesn't work".